Can a minisplit be plugged into a generator?
I am considering buying a minisplit system in my home's upstairs. We are working with a reputable dealer/installer. We have no current AC, and the ducting (which is retrofit) very poorly heats the upstairs. We are also considering the value of better emergency preparedness.
Our house is poorly prepared for emergencies. The rare, once-in-five-year ice storm is prone to knocking out power due to careless drivers and raised lines. While our house has mainly a gas blower furnace to heat, the system is controlled by a 15A dedicated circuit. In order to get the small electrical power to operate this, an interlock install, permit, and general panel re-arrangement is far too much money.
Since the mini split has an outside outlet, I wonder why I can't plug it directly into a generator. I am not sure the outlet style (3 or 4 prong 240V outlet, like a stove I assume). According to the vendor this is not possible, but rather they quoted me on the above interlock and panel revision which I already determined not to be of great value.
Photo of panel here:


1 - For most (not all) people, refrigerators and similar critical equipment are more important in an outage than HVAC (except heating in below-freezing weather), so an interlock setup that lets you power multiple circuits makes a lot of sense; 2 - interlock, etc. may or may not require a panel replacement - pictures of the existing panel would help a lot, 3 - outdoor HVAC equipment is normally hardwired, not plug/cord connected.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact photo added, except slots 29/30 recently added 20A for receptacles/lights in basement reno. Also the 30A double pole for water heater is deprecated but a tankless was added before I moved in (they never removed the old circuit)(.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact are you saying the code requirement for the "receptacle" within a certain number of feet of an outdoor unit does not mean the receptacle has a removable plug?

The receptacle near an outdoor unit (a relatively new requirement, by the way) is for service/maintenance equipment - e.g., refrigerant recovery. It can (provided it is placed strategically) double as a regular outdoor receptacle for homeowner use. But it is NOT for permanent connection of HVAC equipment. HVAC equipment (except something like a window air conditioner) should always be hardwired for safety and reliability.

If in an emergency, you probably could wire a plug onto the mini split cable and plug it into a generator big enough to power it.  Then after an hour plug in fridge, then the microwave, then some lights.  If you want the house to be prepared, a generator big enough for all the stuff wanted to be powered, an interlock/breaker/inlet seems to be less of a PITA.  The stuff is not rocket science, so doing the labour yourself after getting all the parts will save money, if in your own single detached family home.

Given the relatively low cost of an honest and proper sliding-plate generator interlock, I would advise going that way.    Your mini-split is not allowed to be "cord-and-plug connected" so if you wanted to run it off a plug, you would need to replace the disconnect with a 6-space subpanel containing a sliding-plate generator interlock and inlet.   So you might as well just put that in the main panel and be able to power the fridge and lighting too.  (or any sensible number of things).   Note that extension cords through cracked doors kill people via carbon monoxide.
